# In apache nifi can getsftp be a subsequent processor

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry, apache-nifi-toolkit

I have a file containing a bunch of folder names in it. After using `getfile` to get the data from the file, I'm splitting the data into strings in different queue and each queue contains the name of the folder in the attribute of flowfile.

[image: Image of queues where each queue have a foldername in it in its FolderName attribute]

Now I want to pass those queues to `getsftp` processor where I'll use `$FolderName` attribute in the `Remote Path` property of the processor to fetch data based on it.

Here the problem is that when I'm trying to connect any queue's success or failure to `getsftp` processor, it is not allowing me to connect to it. Here I researched and came to know that `getsftp` can't be subsequent processor of any other processor and only it can be parent of processors.

Is there any way to make `getsftp` a subsequent processor of any other processor? If no then is there any way where I can store the values of queues and then use that values in the `Remote Path` property of the processor to fetch data based on it?

Comment: Instead of storing bunch of SFTP folder names in the input file, can you store the list of SFTP file names (in the format of `$folder/$filename`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No processor in NiFi can read a SFTP `$foldername` dynamically from a flow-file attribute and read all the file contents under the folder. You have to do some workaround - I have listed 2 workarounds as 2 separate answers.

I always use the combination of `ListSFTP` and `FetchSFTP`(which accepts an incoming connection). For your use case (you don't need `ListSFTP`), just connect the queue from your screenshot to the `FetchSFTP` processor and you should be good to go.
Note: [FetchSFTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchSFTP/) can only read contents of an SFTP file. So this will only work if you know the SFTP `$path` and `$filename` variables (i.e., complete name of the SFTP file to be read)
[image: Incoming connection to FetchSFTP]
I have explained the usage of `ListSFTP` and `FetchSFTP` processors as a separate answer.

Comment: In getSFTP processor I have a property named Remote Path where I can mention folder name of my sftp and it will get all files present in that folder. In fetchSFTP where can I write the folder name to fetch all its file?

Comment: @justlearner `FetchSFTP` has a property named `Remote File`. I have updated my answer with the `FetchSFTP` processor properties. If you want to get a list of files from a folder, use `ListSFTP` processor (specify your `$folderName` there) and connect it's output to `FetchSFTP` processor (look at the screenshots in the answer)

Comment: Thank you for your effort @P K it means a lot. I hope this post would help other developers as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read all the files from an SFTP folder, use [ListSFTP processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListSFTP/) (specify your `$folderName` in the `Remote Path` property that currently has a `.`). This will return you one flowFile for every file under the folder (flowFile will have attributes `${path}` and `${filename}`). Use these attributes in [FetchSFTP processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchSFTP/)

[image: ListSFTP processor properties]

Here is the [FetchSFTP processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchSFTP/) properties you were interested
[image]

This is our current PROD setup (which is working fine for years)

Comment: in the Remote file parameter, you've mentioned '${path}/${filename}' which indicates that I've passed the folder name through the **path** attribute and name of a specific file using **filename**. Correct?

Comment: That’s correct @justlearner. Just for clarity, the path is not just the foldername, it should be the absolute path of the folder (example `${path}` is /usr/local/folder)

Comment: suppose by using the path variable I gave the exact location of the folder but will I get all the files present in that folder? I want to get all the file names present in the folder. So if I pass ${path} will I get the names of all the files present?

Comment: Which processor you are talking about? `ListSFTP` or `FetchSFTP`.
<<Copy-paste from my answer>>
If you want to read all the files from an SFTP folder, use ListSFTP processor (specify your $folderName in the Remote Path property that currently has a .). This will return you one flowFile for every file under the folder (flowFile will have attributes ${path} and ${filename}). Use these attributes in FetchSFTP processor